# Requiring node.js libraries from nunjucks

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

Is there a way to require a node.js library from inside a nunjucks template?

Something similar to the following:

```
{% set strftime = require('strftime') %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var env = nunjucks.configure([...
...
env.addGlobal('require', function(lib) { 
    return require(lib);
});
```